# Conditional Expectation(s) of Multiple Random Variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable

I am having a bit of trouble with one of the problems I am working right now.

The problem is:

"What is $E\left \{ E\left \{ E\left \{ Z \mid X , Y \right \} \right \} \right \}$ ?"

During an office hours the professor explained that it would be necessary to use a "probability chain rule" and that you would need to use the following relationship:
$f\left ( x,y,z \right )= f\left ( x \mid y,z \right)f\left( y\mid z \right )f\left(z \right )$

I am having some trouble seeing how they relate, and also what the actual problem is looking for as well.

Naturally, I am not looking for the answer, but rather a path to the answer.  I know I have already been given that path by the professor, but it still does not make much sense to me.

Any help anyone could provide would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The notation
$$\mathbb E\left \{ \mathbb E\left \{ \mathbb E\left \{ Z \mid X , Y \right \} \right \} \right \}$$
is incorrect, it should be
$$\mathbb E [ \overbrace{\mathbb E \{ \underbrace{\mathbb E( Z \mid X , Y )}_\text{function of $(X,Y)$} \mid X \}}^\text{function of $X$}]$$
or
$$\mathbb E [ \overbrace{\mathbb E \{ \underbrace{\mathbb E( Z \mid X , Y )}_\text{function of $(X,Y)$} \mid Y \}}^\text{function of $Y$}]$$

Comment: Xi'an, thank you for the feedback.  I wish the notation was incorrect, but all I am given is exactly what is in the original question.  This question, I think, has been used for years by the same professor, so I believe he would have changed it by now if the notation was incorrect for the answer he is looking for.

Comment: The inner expectation provides a function of $(X,Y)$, but the following two expectations are not uniquely defined and are missing a supplementary conditioning. That someone has used the notation for several years is not a mathematical argument for validity!

Comment: Xi'an, I agree totally!  However, that is all the information I have to work with and I have to enter these problems with some sort of notional assumption that the notation is correct, or is at least as intended.  I just do not know enough about the material to determine if the notation is incorrect.  When I have an answer to this from the professor I will post it.

Comment: I interpret the notation differently: the inner expectation is a function of $(X,Y),$ whence the next expectation is the expectation of this *bivariate* variable--a vector--and finally the outer expectation operator is either nonsensical or should be understood as treating that vector as a constant random variable (making it superfluous).

Comment: You could improve the notation by adding the variables which the expectation takes into account as an index